# Equivalent constant arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Is it true that the equivalent of

```
const char arr[2] = {0, 0};
```

is

```
const char *const arr = "\0\0";
```

but not

```
const char * arr = "\0\0";
```

Does an array have a secret `const`? My instincts say yes, because you can't assign an array to another. (`arr = arr2;` `error: assignment to expression with array type`)

I'm asking, because I'm going to use a global array constant.

Comment: This is tricky, because in the middle case, you could still attempt e.g. `*(const char **)(&arr) = foo;`. So, your question is posed in a way that does not permit the correct answer, which is that arrays and pointers are not equivalent; the name of an array is just converted to a pointer to its first member in expressions (see e.g. C11 6.3.2.1p3). This converted pointer is not an *lvalue* so it cannot be assigned to.

Comment: Note size of _string literal_ `"\0\0"` is 3.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1 :-** The statement

```
const char arr[2] = {0, 0};
```

Here `arr` is array of two characters and both `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are initialized with `0`. `const` represents that you can't change `arr[0]` & `arr[1]`. for e.g

```
 int main(void) {
        const char arr[2] = {0, 0};
        arr[0] = 'a';/* not possible, by putting const in front you made arr[0] as read only */
        return 0;
}
```

**Case 2 :-** The statement

```
  const char *const arr = "\0\0";
```

Here also `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are initialized with `\0`. But that syntax meaning is that `arr` is **constant pointer** & where its pointing that data also **read only** i.e you can't modify `arr[0]` & you can't modify `arr`. for e.g

```
int main(void) {
        const char *const arr = "\0\0"; 
        arr = "hello"; /*not possible, read only arr */
        *arr = 'a'; /* not possible, can't change the arr[0] */ 
        return 0;
}
```

**Case 3 :-** The statement

```
const char * arr = "\0\0";
```

Here `arr` is a char pointer & where its pointing, on that memory location whatever data is there, that is **read only** though it causes undefined behavior, but you can change the `arr` i.e `arr` now points to `"\0\0"`, it can points to other memory location also. for e.g

```
int main(void) {
        const char * arr = "\0\0";
        arr++; /* possible bcz arr is not constant pointer */
        *arr = 'a'; /* not possible, can't change the arr[0] */
        return 0;
}
```

*Does an array have a secret const?*  No, **array** is not a **pointer** but its a **constant pointer**, as array name represents base address & that's constant i.e you can't modify that. for e.g

```
char arr1[] = "hello",arr2[10];
```

Here you can't do `arr1 = arr2` because `arr1` is constant pointer i.e can't change address, but you can change its elements value.

Note that both `const char arr[10];` and `char arr[10];` are different.

Comment: Detail about "read only".  `arr` in `const char * arr` does not point to _read-only data_.  To attempt to write to data pointed to by the address in `arr` is _undefined behavior_.  It might "work", it might not, It is UB.  So best not to try to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. Arrays and pointers are different animals. An array represent a number of consecutive elements of the same type, and has a *size* which is the size of an individual item multiplied by the number of its elements. It will always represent the same *memory zone* along its full life time.

On the other hand, a pointer is a designator or a reference for the first element of an array - a single variable is assimilated to an array of size 1 for that point. It has no notion of the size of its pointed array, and the size of a pointer is just what the implementation needs to represent a memory address. If T is a type and if `int_ptr` is valid in an implementation, the following equality is true:

```
sizeof(T *) == sizeof(int_ptr)
```

A pointer can normally point to different variables or *memory zones* throughout its lifetime. Of course it can be made const and in that case changing its value will invoke undefined behaviour but could be allowed by the compiler, while you can never change the position of an array.

Now for your examples:

```
const char arr[2] = {0, 0};
```

`arr` is a true array: `arr = x;` will raise a compilation error and `sizeof(arr)` is 2

```
const char *const arr = "\0\0";
```

`arr` is is const pointer to const char. `arr = x;` will be rejected but `(const char *) arr = x;` will be accepted at compile time (and will invoke UB at run time). But except in a 16 bits environment `sizeof(arr)` is not 2 but is the size of a pointer (4 in 32 bits environments, 8 in 64 bits ones)

```
const char *arr = "\0\0";
```

`arr` is is pointer to const char. `arr = "abcd";` is legal and will have `arr` point to a different string literal of a different size. Its size is still the size of a pointer.

---

Unrelated to the question, but there is another important difference between arrays and pointers in a non const use case:

```
char arr[2] = "a";
```

here `arr` is an array *initialized* with the characters 'a' and '\0'. `arr[0] = 'b';` is legal

```
char *arr = "a";
```

here `arr` is a pointer to a literal string. As literal strings are const, `arr[0] = 'b';` invokes UB. (modern compilers should issue a warning for `char *arr = "a";` but for compatibility reasons they are not required to)

---

BTW, the confusion between arrays and pointers is that array can be automatically converted to pointers when you use their value:

```
   char arr[] = "abc";    // array of size 4 

   f(arr);                // the f function receives a pointer to the first element of arr
```